# ¿ Cómo ejecutar mi modal que pertencece a otro componente?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

mirén mi código es el siguiente, y mi intención es  que al pulsar este botón se cargue el modal creado con bootstrap pertenece a otro componente. Mi intención es que el codigo en la landing principal llame al modal creado en su componente a parte.
Botón:

```
<a id="btn_main_contratar" class="btn btn-primary-gradient openBtn" data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#myModal"> </a>
```

Mi función con JavaScript es la siguiente:

/*

```
    <script>   $('.openBtn').on('click',function(){
console.log("eeee")
    $('#myModal').modal({ show:true}); 
});
</script>
```

Y el modal de Boostrap este:

```
<div class="modal fade openBtn" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog superpos">
                    <div class="modal-content superpos">
                         <div class="modal-header superpos">

                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>

                  <div class="modal-body">
   <h1>EEEEEEEE </h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

https://docs.google.com/document/d/16v5BZ29YsPQ6GgOetB-QTavhlYVefco1_Hhigvwd7Xc/edit?usp=sharing

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, ¿qué problema sufres? Debería funcionar perfectamente. Por cierto, el código javascript sería innecesario si usas `data-toggle="modal"`.

Comment: Pues, no me abre el modal, y el console log solo aparece la primera vez de pulsar el botón, es raro, no entiendo porque..

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código completo del HTML? Si quieres, para no hacer muy larga la pregunta, compártelo en algún servicio como drive, mega, onedrive, etc.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16v5BZ29YsPQ6GgOetB-QTavhlYVefco1_Hhigvwd7Xc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Acabo de mirar en tu código que existen dos elementos `<div>` con el mismo `id` (`id="myModal"`). Deberías revisar eso y poner un `id` diferente para cada modal. Aunque pueda haber dos botones que abran el mismo modal, los `id` de los modales deben ser únicos.

Comment: ¿Cuando hablas de componentes es porque tienes el **HTML** de la modal en otro fichero al del botón con el que quieres abrirla?

Comment: Sii, asi mismo, no consigo que me saque el modal, pero si entra en la funcion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como puedes ver, tu código funciona correctamente (uses o no el evento "click" del botón):

```js
// No hace falta para nada
/*$('.openBtn').on('click', function() {
    console.log("eeee");
    $('#myModal').modal({ show:true}); 
});*/
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a id="btn_main_contratar" class="btn btn-primary openBtn"
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">botón</a>

<div class="modal fade openBtn" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog superpos">
        <div class="modal-content superpos">
            <div class="modal-header superpos">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>EEEEEEEE</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- A partir de aquí son cierres de div que te faltan -->
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Edito: En el archivo compartido existen dos elementos `<div>` con el mismo `id` (`id="myModal"`). Deberías revisar eso y poner un `id` diferente para cada modal. Aunque pueda haber dos botones que abran el mismo modal, **los `id` de los modales** (o, en general, de cualquier elemento) **deben ser únicos**.

Comment: Ese era el error.. tontería total, perdona y gracias

Comment: Solucionado, gracias. Era el error por el segundo div con Id similar.

Comment: Un placer haber sido de ayuda. No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta pulsando en el tick a la izquierda de la pregunta, bajo el número de votos (por ahora uno). Gracias.

Comment: @pablovva si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada y considera darle un +1. Lee sobre [qué hacer cuando alguien responde a tu pregunta](/help/someone-answers)